# Constructor Injection in Xamarin Froms .xaml.cs file classes

Tags: c#, xamarin, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, mobile-development

I want to take advantage of dependency injection in my Xamarin project but can't get constructor injection to work in C# classes behind XAML views. Is there any way to do it ?
I've seen guides how to setup dependency injections in View Models, to later use them as repositories but that doesn't work for me.

So far I tried Ninject and Unity.

Code:
This is the service I want to use inside of my PCL project:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public void Add(string myNote)
    {
        //Add Note logic
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
 public interface IMyService
 {
    void Add(string myNote);
 }
```

Unity setup in App.Xaml:

```
public App ()
{
   InitializeComponent();

    var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
     unityContainer.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>();

    var unityServiceLocator = new UnityServiceLocator(unityContainer);              
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => unityServiceLocator);

    MainPage = new MainMasterMenu(); //<-- feel that I'm missing something here as I shouldn't be creating class instances with DI, right ?
}
```

Usage that I'd like to see. This is .CS file behind a XAML starting page:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MainMasterMenu : MasterDetailPage
{
    private IMyService _myService;
    public MainMasterMenu(IMyService myService)
    {
      _myService = myService
    }

   private void SomeFormControlClickEvent(object sender, ItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
     _myService.Add("hi");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that simple example creating the `MainMasterMenu` directly would be no issue, but you would have to pass the reference to your service

```
MainPage = new MainMasterMenu(unityContainer.Resolve<IMyService>());
```

But this would mean that you'll have to change that line every time the constructor of `MainMasterMenu` changes. You could circumvent this by registering the `MainMasterMenu`, too.

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<MainMasterMenu>();
...
MainPage = unityContainer.Resolve<MainMasterPage>();
```

Anyway, anytime you want to navigate to another page, which needs any dependency registered with unity, you'll have to make sure to resolve its dependencies properly, which requires (at least indirect) access to the unity container. You could pass a wrapper that encapsules the access to unity

```
interface IPageResolver
{
    T ResolvePage<T>()
        where T : Page;
}
```

and then implement that resolver with unity

```
public class UnityPageResolver
{
    private IUnityContainer unityContainer;

    public UnityPageResolver(IUnityContainer unityContainer)
    {
        this.unityContainer = unityContainer;
    }

    public T ResolvePage<T>()
        where T : Page // do we need this restriction here?
    {
        return unityContainer.Resolve<T>();
    }
}
```

This gets registered with unity

```
unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IUnityContainer>(this);
unityContainer.RegisterType<IPageResolver, UnityPageResolver>();
```

But you should have a look at the Prism library ([see here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism)) that solves many of the issues (e.g. it provides an `INavigationService` that lets you navigate to other pages without caring about the dependencies and it provides facilities to resolve viewmodels automatically, including dependencies).

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try and will report back.